# How to check if event clientx, clienty is present within getBoundingClientRect?

Tags: javascript, dom, element, viewport, getboundingclientrect

I have an xy object from an mouseup event and I want to know if the xy is present within boundingClientRect of an element in the viewport. I am able to get left, right, top, bottom values of the element from getBoundingClientRect method. I want to know whether xy is within the element rect.

Comment: "_xy object_"? Do you mean coordinates?

Comment: yes. `{ xy: { x: 123, y: 234 } }`

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` does not exactly provide an `xy` property that contains an `{x: n, y: n}` object

Comment: @AbanaClara : yes I have a separate xy object from event. Want to check if the coordinates is within area of the rect of the element

Comment: Compare `xy.x` to `cR.left` and `cR.right`, and `xy.y` to `cR.top` and `cR.bottom`. You may also need to fit the coordinates to the same `offsetParent` as the client rect has.

Comment: You can use `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint` to achieve the same result without doing computations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about the `clientX` and `clientY` properties of a mouse event. If this is right, then the point and the rect are relative to the same coordinate area, and the following is true:

If `x` is between `left` and `right` and `y` between `bottom` and `top`, the point is in the box.

Comment: Thanks. No api from javascript?. If so, this seems the only option.

Comment: Nope, just the math :)

Comment: I find a 20px difference between the clientX and rect.right at the right edge of a div. ChatGPT has some suggestions, but they don't sound likely to me.